# Groovy scripts on Ubuntu Server - unable to resolve class

Tags: docker, ubuntu, groovy, server, classpath

I am completely new in Ubuntu Server and configuring docker containers...

On my Ubuntu Server I have simple groovy script:

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.Repository

repository.repositoryManager.browse().each { Repository repo ->
    println repo.name
}
```

... using [Nexus Public API](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/master/components/nexus-repository/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/repository/Repository.java) to print list of created nexus repos.

After I run it the output was:

```
/usr/bin/build-classpath: Could not find ../../jvm/java/lib Java extension 
for this JVM /usr/bin/build-classpath: error: Some specified jars were not found
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startupfailed:
/usr/bin/scripts/list.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class org.sonatype.nexus.repository.Repository
@ line 1, column 1.
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.Repository
^
```

I have made some investigation and I found out that there must be 1) jar file on server and 2) added to CLASSPATH. Am I right? If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Grape` annotation to get the packages and add them to the classpath. This will make your script portable instead of relying on a classpath.

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html

i.e:

```
@Grab('org.springframework:spring-orm:3.2.5.RELEASE')
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
```

Look for the package you need in maven repository and add the dependency via grape.

**Update**

Seems that you need more packages, not just the nexus-repository from maven.